# Variable in Function not reachable

Tags: php, function, variables, is-empty

i am writing a customer database. I've got a function to show all customers that looks like this.

```
<?php
class customer{

public function getAllCustomers(){
    global $database;
    $query = $database->query('SELECT * FROM hs_customers');
    $result = $database->statement->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
}
?>
```

Until up here everything works well. Its connecting, im getting data and so on. The only thing i am unhappy with is i don't want the database name to be hardcoded inside the function, furthermore i want it to be replaced by a variable. So id did the following (as i did before, and it worked out well) but suddenly it wont replace the variable anymore?...

```
<?php
class customer{

private $customerDB = 'hs_customers';

public function getAllCustomers(){
    global $database;
    $query = $database->query('SELECT * FROM :db', array(':db' => $customerDB));
    $result = $database->statement->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
}
?>
```

I guess i've got something wrong. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variable containers on syntax that is used by SQL, e.g. a `table name` or anything else related to the syntax like `order`, `group` etc. So in order to dynamically do this you have to escape the SQL string and use it like

```
$query = $database->query('SELECT * FROM '.($this->customerDB));
```

-- update for @TimG

And because you are in a class environment, the variable `$customerDB` should be treated as a class property. You have to use `$this->` assignment to use any property of a class, unless it is static in that case, use `self::`.

Comment: Works :). Thank you! And everyone else too!

Comment: this answer is correct, but fails to address *both* problems the OP had.  You should update your answer with info regarding the lack of `$this` but still +1 for seeing a problem that is non-obvious at first glance. :)

Answer (score 4):

PHP requires you to use [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) when accessing class members from within methods:

```
array(':db' => $this->customerDB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to replace variables, you need to use the statement `prepare` like this :

```
$Var1 = 'Allo';
$Var2 = 30;

$Query = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 = :Data1 AND Field2 = :Data2');
$Query->bindValue(':Data1', $Var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Query->bindParam(':Data2', $Var2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Query->execute();
```

`bindValue` will directly bind the value to the query.

`bindParam` will bind the variable name as "static". If you edit the variable before running `execute`, the content of the variable will follow.

Also, in your case, you need to use `$this->customerDB`, not `$customerDB`. The variable you are referring is in a class, use `$this` to access class level content.